# Vector calculus problem, constant speed, counterclockwise or clockwise.

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

I'm stuck on how to do this problem:
$\displaystyle \vec{r}(t)=(\cos t)\,\vec{i}+(\sin t)\,\vec{j}, \qquad t \geq 0.$.

**Does the particle have constant speed? (yes or no)**

For this one I was thinking of finding the velocity and testing a lot of v values in the equation to see if it was constant.

**Is the particle's acceleration vector always orthogonal to its velocity vector? (yes or no)**
For this one I was thinking of finding the velocity and acceleration vector and using dot product to see if it was orgthagonal or not.

**Does the particle move clockwise or counterclockwise around the circle? (clockwise, counterclockwise, both, or neither)**
I am not sure for this one

Does the particle begin at the point (1,0)? (yes or no)
Not sure for this one.
i will appecriate the help! thank u!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The speed is defined as the norm of the velocity vector. Assuming the $r(t)$ is the placement, then you'll have to take derivative to get the velocity first. Still it's clear that the speed would be constant.
2. Again, we just need to compute the acceleration vector.
3. Just plug in $t=0$, $t=\frac{1}{2}$ and $t=1$ and see what you get.

Comment: what does the "norm of the velocity vector" mean?

Comment: @Elsa It means the magnitude of a vector.

Comment: when does it not have constant speed? like when would a particle not have constant speed?

Comment: @Elsa Why $\textit{does}$ the velocity in your question have constant speed? What about a velocity vector like $v(t)=(\sin(t),\sin(t))$?

Comment: well for that, the speed would be square root of (sin^2t+sin^2t), and that changes depending on t @misakov

Comment: @Elsa That is correct. The interesting part about the velocity in your question is that the speed is constant, yet the velocity is not. If you took any physics class, you will recognize that it actually describes a motion.

Comment: so im doing another problem right now like this and the speed im getting is square root of (49sin^2(7t)+49cos^2(7t)). would this ones speed be 1 as well?

Comment: What does your calculation tell you? @Elsa